# How to create a table in PDF file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

Let's say I have some data from MySQL using fetchall(). How do I generate a table in PDF format? I've been digging around for quite some time but it seems I'm running into dead ends.

It does not need to look pretty, a basic tabular structure will do.

```
header = ['User ID', 'Name', 'Age']
data = mycursor.fetchall()


tableToPDF(header, data)
```

Is there a library that is capable of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

It would be a detour but you could use python-docx to create the document in Microsoft Word format (or Open Office I guess) then convert to PDF.

Comment: Actually, any printable format will do! Can you maybe shed some light on this? Thanks!

Comment: Look here : https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ You can construct the document the way you want using this module.

Comment: Thank you so much for the recommendation! It's fast and easy. Got it up and running within minutes.